# How to optimize the following function?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, conditional

Consider the following function:

```
 function[x_, y_] = If[x < Exp[y], Sqrt[1 - x/Exp[y]], 0];
functionTotal1[x_] = Sum[function[x, 0.02*j], {j, 0, 4*10^5, 1}];
```

Calling this function is very slow:

```
AbsoluteTiming[functionTotal1[2]]
```

gives 1.5 seconds. This is probably related to If condition. What is a possible way to make calling faster, apart from making an interpolation?

Comment: If you have a multicore CPU you can use `ParallelSum`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`Ramp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp) and vectorized operations:

```
y = -.02 Range[0, 4 10^5];
Total @ Sqrt[Ramp[1 - 2 Exp[y]]] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.018728, 399935.}

Comment: H o l y  c o w ! :-)

Answer (score 4):

On my machine

```
function[x_, y_] := If[x < Exp[y], Sqrt[1 - x/Exp[y]], 0];
functionTotal1[x_] := Sum[function[x, 0.02*j], {j, 0, 4*10^5, 1}];
RepeatedTiming[functionTotal1[2]]
```

> {6.631, 399935.}

Here are a few things that I noticed that speed up evaluation.

## Each term is real or imaginary

First we see that if $x \leq \exp(y)$, then $\sqrt{1-x e^{-y}}$ is real, and if $x > \exp(y)$, then $\sqrt{1-x e^{-y}}$ is **strictly imaginary**.  Therefore, if we get rid of the `If` and ignore all the imaginary terms (effectively setting each term where $x > \exp(y)$ to zero)

```
f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[1 - x/Exp[y]]
ftot[x_] := Re@Sum[f[x, 0.02*j], {j, 0., 4.*10^5}]
RepeatedTiming[ftot[2]]
```

> {5.3, 399935.}

## Vectorization and packed arrays

With the thought of restructuring the `Sum` into a `Dot` to utilize vectorization, we rewrite the term $\sqrt{1-x e^{-y}}$ into a product of terms as $e^{-y/2} \sqrt{e^y-x}$.  Then, skipping the declaration of the "term" function, the sum can be written as

```
ftotdot[x_] := Dot @@ (Transpose@Table[{Exp[-0.02 y/2], Sqrt[Exp[0.02 y] - x]}, {y, 0., 4.*10^5}]) // Re
ftotdot[2] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {2.91, 399935.}

Then, since `Exp` and arithmetic operators are vectorized we can replace the `Table` with an evaluation of the packed array in `Range`.

```
ftotdot2[x_] := Exp[-#/2].Sqrt[Exp[#] - x] &[0.02 Range[0., 4.*10^5]]) // Re
ftotdot2[2] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {2.3, 399935.}

Further improvements may include the use of `SparseArray`s, `Compile`, even just parallelization.